# Connect rxjs websocket to spring boot server

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, spring-boot, rxjs

I am new to rxjs and I want to connect a simple websocket (In my case I want make the connection with socket.io. I don't know if this is possible or not.)

I have my rxjs component here:

```
export function SmartHome(sources, tabSelectedSubject$) {

const socket = new IO();
socket.connect('ws://localhost:8180/devices/latest-updates');

const vdom$ = view(
    model(
        intent(sources.DOM, sources)
    )
)

const sinks = {
    DOM: vdom$,
}

return sinks
}
```

And I have my Spring Boot server with the following class:

```
public class UserHandshakeInterceptor extends HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor {
private static final String URI_Template = "/devices/latest-updates";

@Override
public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                               WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map <String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
    return super.beforeHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, attributes);
}
}
```

How can I make the connection to the server, because it gave me a cross-origin exception?